# jQuery - .on scroll not working on newly added div

Tags: jquery, events, scroll

I have a button "Window Add" and after clicking it, a new div should be added to the dom. The scroll event on the new div does not want to get attached to it and show the alert when scrolled. I know that since it's newly added, we need to integrate the on event handler, but that still did not work for me. Here is what I tried:

```
<div id="window-add">Window Add</div>

$('#window-add').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<div id="scroll-window">Scroll Me.</div>');
});

//using on doesn't work below either
$('#scroll-window').scroll(function(){
    alert('scrolling');
});
```

Any idea on how to get this to work?
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJFCz/13/)

Comment: make sure you're not adding elements with same id multiple times in your document.

Comment: @Ejay I'm sure Ejay. Check out the fiddle

Comment: did you try setting the overflow to scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **ID** MUST be unique per page. (You're adding multiple IDs)
2. You're just adding **non-scrollable** elements to **body**.

   Than scrolling actually the **body** element you cannot expect `$('#scroll-window')` to call a `scroll` event.

Using jQuery **1.6.4** (Lilke in your fiddle) you have to do somethog like this using `.bind()`:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rJFCz/18/)**</kbd>

```
var scrollWindow = $('<div>', {
    id:"scroll-window",
    html: "Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me.Scroll Me."
});


$('#window-add').click(function(){
    $(this).after(scrollWindow);
});

// IF YOU USE jQ (1.7+) you can use .on() method instead of .bind()
scrollWindow.bind('scroll', function(){
    alert('scrolling');
});
```

> jQuery <1.7 use .bind()
>   jQuery 1.7+ use .on()

Comment: ok, sorry for the complication. If you click it once, it will be unique (so just click it once). I then tried to use .on to register the scroll on the new window but it won't work

Comment: @Wonka what you mean by saying "new window"? What's a new window? only `$(window)` will register the `scroll event` http://jsfiddle.net/rJFCz/10/ unless you use an CSS overflow for your added elements.

Comment: @Wonka but you need to apply scrollbars to your `new` element, currently `body` has scrollbars. Gotcha?

Comment: I'm trying not to use window as the selector here as it is used in other areas not shown here

Comment: So basically now the scroll bars appear in the new div, but scrolling still won't alert

Comment: @Wonka added a demo and an example how to do it.

Comment: wow, this works but seems pretty complex for such a simple thing. Do you mind a small explanation why we must create a variable out of the div instead of pass the selector and have bind/on take care of it? Treat it as the deprecated live? Thank you for a working solution though!

Comment: @Wonka I don't know exactly why it does not work using a classic event delegation (like `.on()` does), so I decided to make an in-memory element, that way jQuery will know what element to delegate the `scroll` (looks-like-issue-prone) event.

Comment: Thanks roXon hope they fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#window-add').click(function () {
  $(this).after('<div id="scroll-window">Scroll Me.</div>');
  $(window, this).scroll(function () {
    alert('scrolling');
  });
});
```

Will this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/rJFCz/3/